# Grails run-app has to be executed twice

Tags: grails

I have to run start-app twice. On the first run my console reports an error:

```
| Running application...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'' finished with
non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

But on the second run, it runs perfectly. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Run the `JVM with -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m` (or any big number) (or -Xmx512m for short)

Answer (score 0):

**In buildconfig.groovy Increase values for mxPerm and maxMemory**

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```